# Xcode keeps crashing

Tags: xcode, crash, osx-mountain-lion

I just started out programming for iOS. I tried adding an enter button for a simple calculator and changing its size, but Xcode keeps crashing. This is the report:

```
Process:         Xcode [406]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:      com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:         4.5.1 (1842)

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
ProductBuildVersion: 4G1004
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouch-1929/IBPlugin/Utilities/IBObjectMarshalling.m:651
Details:  Failed to arbitrate IBNSLayoutConstraint, IBUIButton, IBUILabel, IBUIView, and IBUIViewController.

Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iOS Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

Exception name: IBAssertionFailure
Exception reason: ASSERTION FAILURE: 
Reason:     All views needing candidate constraints have already had constraints generated. This most likely indicates a bug involving layout of the following views:
    Layout engine frame ({{20, 20}, {282, 36}}) of <UILabel: 0x81f5560; frame = (20 20; 281 36); text = '0'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; autoresize = TM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x815cdd0>> does not match canvas frame ({{20, 20}, {281, 36}})
```

I've already tried reinstalling Xcode and resetting iOS simulator as well. I have Mountain Lion.

Comment: My guess is that you've got a corrupted xib file.

Comment: Verify that your constraints have a multiplier different from 0

Answer (score 2):

Try this steps:

> 1) Right click on Storyboard in the navigator
>
> 2) Click on Show File Inspector
>
> 3) Uncheck "Use Autolayout"

Hope this helps